# Intellij in linux showing unresolved reference after installing all packages

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I installed intellij in linux, and installed all python related packages (`make install`), however it is always highlighting that the imports as unresolved. Noting that it is working in jupyter lab.
So what's wrong?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: yes it did not work @y.bedrov

Comment: Does the code run? If it runs, it means the IDE couldn't index the modules for some reason. There could be various causes for this issue. Please submit a support ticket with JetBrains at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?pycharm and provide Logs from **Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data** as well as the output of the [interpreter diagnostic script](https://gist.github.com/aresler/22c59d7883fd57dddb4c57a7f96603d6)